# Using UISearchController to display search results and keyboard covers bottom rows/sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

There is a UISearchController which displays search results in UITableView that is split into alphabetical sections and corresponding rows based on a contacts name.

When there is a search result that displays a few contacts larger than the UITableView with the keyboard displayed, the bottom rows and sections will be covered by the keyboard.

What is the best way to increase the UITableView content height when displaying a filtered search result so that the contacts at the bottom can be scrolled to and become visible to the user so they will not be covered by the iOS keyboard anymore?

I am using Swift 3.1 and a UISearchResultsUpdating delegate with the updateSearchResults method to display the filtered results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care when the keyboard appears/disappears and set the tableView's `contentInset` accordingly.

In your TableViewController class create two functions as responders to the keyboard events:

```
func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyBoardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyBoardSize.height, right: 0)
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    }
}

func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

And register/deregister the responders in `ViewDidLoad` and `deinit`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...

    // register the responders
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4.2 and higher.
Register an observer.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // register the responders
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification , object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

As of iOS 9 (and OS X 10.11), you don't need to remove observers yourself, if you're not using block based observers though. The system will do it for you, since it uses zeroing-weak references for observers, where it can.

Functions that respond to an event.

```
@objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyBoardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyBoardSize.height, right: 0)
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    }
}

@objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```